# Problems with mouse events on newly created CKEditor instance

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to create a create a new CKEditor ver4 instance in response to the user clicking on an element.  Due to the nature of the application, I can not use the "autoInline" feature as outlined in the [CKEditor Sample](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline).  While the sample below does in fact create an editor instance, that instance has a significant problem.  Inline instances are supposed to disappear when the user clicks away from them.  In this example however, the user must first click away, click back into the instance, and then click away again.  How can I prevent this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jspath/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>
        var editor = null;
        CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
        function init() {
        var e2 = document.getElementById("element2");
        e2.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if(!editor) {
                editor = CKEDITOR.inline(e2);
                editor.on('instanceReady', function () {
                    console.log("instanceReady")
                    console.log(editor.focusManager.hasFocus);
                });
                editor.on('focus', function() {
                    console.log("focus");
                })
                editor.on('blur', function() {
                    console.log("blur");
                    editor.destroy();
                    editor = null;
                })
            }
        })
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div tabindex="0" id="element2" style="background-color: yellow;" contentEditable = true>Element 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've had the same issue. Not managed to fix it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that `editor.focusManager.hasFocus` was true, the editor's element did not in fact have focus.  Perhaps this is a bug?  Anyway, adding `editor.focus();` to the `instanceReady` function resolved the issue.